# How to sort a 2d array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a 2d array

```
{{7,2},{2,4},{2,1},{4,9},{4,2},{3,4},{3,2},{3,1}}
```

I want to sort the array according to 1st element and then 2nd element and then 3rd element and so on. I want a output like this for the given input

```
{{2,1},{2,4},{3,1},{3,2},{3,4},{4,2},{4,9},{7,2}}
```

I have tried the following code snippet:

```
Comparer<int> comparer = Comparer<int>.Default;
Array.Sort<int[]>(properties, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x[0], y[0]));
```

But this doesn't give me the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Sort` unfortunately is for 1D arrays only.
Also LINQ's OrderBy can not help, at least not directly, because 2d arrays dosn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.
So  copying the data into some easily sortable container seems the way to go.
Then .e.g `List<T>.Sort` or `Enumerable.OrderBy` will do the job just fine.

Here's an example:

```
        //init 2d-array
        int[,] arr2d = { { 7, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 1 }, { 4, 9 }, { 4, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 1 } };

        //copy to List of valuetuples(int, int) to have a sortable enumerable
        var tmp = new List<(int a, int b)>();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr2d.GetLength(0); i++) {
           tmp.Add((arr2d[i,0], arr2d[i,1])); 
        }
        //setup our sorting callback aka Comparison delegate
        Comparison<(int a, int b)> sorter = (t1, t2) => {
                                                var res1 = t1.a - t2.a;
                                                return res1 != 0 ? res1 : t1.b - t2.b;
                                             };
        //do sort
        tmp.Sort(sorter);
        //copy back to an 2d array that now is sorted as desired
        var sortedArr2d = new int[arr2d.GetLength(0), arr2d.GetLength(1)];
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++) {
            sortedArr2d[i, 0] = tmp[i].a;
            sortedArr2d[i, 1] = tmp[i].b;
        }
        //show output (on console for demo)
        for (var i = 0; i < arr2d.GetLength(0); i++) {
           Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}]", sortedArr2d[i, 0], sortedArr2d[i, 1]);
        }
```